# JDBC mssql's tsql not work

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a JDBC program want to use transaction, if statement is a single sql string,
such as:

```
update tab1 set name='killy' where code='admin'
```

but statement contain "if exists...",for example:

```
if exists(select * form tab1 where code='admin') then 
  update tab1 set name='killy' where code='admin' 
else 
  insert into tab1 values('admin','killy')
```

This problem has been confused me.

Comment: I don't get it - what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I try it,it's work well.